# Is this the correct interpretation of the Microsoft statement about support for IE6?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6, activesupport

I have read the questions on Stackoverflow, and plowed through the MS web site a dozen times and it's not at all clear to me what the official statement about support for IE6 is.  Here is the result of my research - just for posterity - and my question is whether this is the correct interpretation, and if not, why not?

It seems that it is considered part of the O/S and as such falls under the support lifecycle for those products.  There are some circular links on the Microsoft support web site between the stated support lifecycle for service packs and the statements about individual components.

The [IE 6 statement is here](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?p1=2073) which links to a generic policy statement.

[This note from Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/gp/lifean24) about IE6 in the wake of IE7 release links it to XP SP2, Win2k SP4 and Server03 SP1.

XP SP2 was superseded by SP3 the release date for which was 21-Apr-2008, and the [support link](http://support.microsoft.com/gp/lifesupsps/#Internet_Explorer) for that is inconclusive since there has been no subsequent service pack release for XP, which means we're back to the generic support lifecycle statement, which is the same for XP SP3 as it is for IE6+XP SP3.

Win2k SP4 follows exactly the same path, but it has an earlier release date, so it can't beat XP SP3.

Server 2003 SP1 is superseded by SP2 which had a release date of 13-Mar-2007, also before XP SP3.

So it seems that it is XP SP3 which is keeping IE6 alive.

So I'm now into understanding the Microsoft Policy on support of products and service packs, which is less than clear to me. This [support lifecycle policy page](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/#tab2) suggests it has a 5 year mainline, 5 year extended lifecycle support phase.  [IE6's stated release date](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?p1=2073) is 31-Dec-2001, which would mean it was due to expire at the end of this year.

However since it seems to be attached to XP, and there have been service packs, it also falls under that part of the policy.  The [Service Pack lifecycle policy](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/#tab2) (I can't bookmark the tab, you have to click on the page to show a div) suggests 24 months, because it is a Windows client product.  There have been no SP's after SP3, so that would be 24 months after 21-Apr-2008, which is 21-Apr-2010.

So, by my reckoning the longest they could claim support is 31-Dec-2011 using the 10 year extended lifecycle support policy based on its release date.

Is that correct?

If so, there will be an enormous party at my place on New Year's Eve.

Comment: That [party](http://ie6funeral.com/) has already [happened](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2010/03/05/microsoft_sends_flowers_to_ie6_funeral/).

Comment: Supported or not by Microsoft; I sure am not.

Comment: Those numbers include consumers and business, mobile and desktop?  I suspect the 0.4% is concentrated on business desktops.

Comment: I don't understand why this was closed.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't call this Microsoft-owned site "supporting" Internet Explorer 6.0:

http://www.ie6countdown.com/

Comment: Heartwarming, but annoyingly there is no end date stated, it is just a plea for people to stop using it.  We're all at the whims of large IT departments too afraid to upgrade.  The only thing I think will kill it is if providers like me put exclusions into our contracts and Microsoft makes an explicit statement about not supporting it.

Comment: Rather than force IE6, simply force a newer OS than XP and that will also solve the problem.

Comment: @Justin Satyr: For a 10-employee shop, that's indeed simple. Don't go to a multinational enterprise with 10^6 computers worldwide with such *simple* advice ("why don't you go out and buy a million new computers, don't tell me the previous ones aren't depreciated already?"). *Large* IT departments is the operative word here (and yes, business-critical internal apps which break horribly in IE7+ are depressingly common).

Comment: I used the word 'simply' a bit tongue-in-cheek, but point taken.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the question whether MS will continue supporting IE 6 is almost meaningless. De-facto they [deprecate it](http://www.ie6countdown.com/).

The only possible influence is for integrators of web-based proprietary systems developed for  a very small amount of dinosaur corporate organizations who will eventually make the move to IE 8 on their old systems, due to the fact that some VP will decide that since MS doesn't cover his ass anymore, they must finally upgrade. Very small amount.

Comment: Not meaningless for me as someone who cannot write support for it out of any contract for my services because Microsoft still apparently officially support it.  There are far more dinosaurs than I'd like to admit.  In fact all our clients, which are some of the biggest retail brands in the world, have IE6.  The unfortunate reality seems to be the dinosaurs still walk the earth.  Government the world over is full of IE6 too.

Answer (score 1):

MS wants IE6 to die just as much as everyone else. I would suggest looking at your target userbase to determine weather or not to support it for your projects.  For me, the default is to not support it at all, unless the client specifically requests it, or if there is a sizeable userbase using that site in IE6 and we choose to support them for that particular project.

Generally speaking, it's pretty rare these days to have a large userbase supporting such an old browser.

I wouldn't factor MS policy into that decision at all.

Comment: Not my experience I'm afraid.  We have 10's of thousands of users hitting our site using IE6.

Comment: Yeah, that's too bad. sometimes a project like that forces you to support it. Not a whole lot you can do about it, unless you add some IE6-only notices that gently remind your users that you're going to be dropping support... Eventually they will have to move on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help you out at all, but if you take a look at the [developer images](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=11575) that Microsoft uses states that the image will become completely useless after November 17, 2011. New years still sounds like a good time to have a party though

Comment: That is a completely diferent deadline. Those VHD images are timebombed, and they're replaced every few months or so (with a new one that is up-to-date and with an extended time limit). The point there is to force the developers testing on those images to test with up-to-date, patched version of the OS.